# clusterize.js with django; static files not found

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, clusterize

I am trying to use the https://clusterize.js.org/ javascript package with my Django website for displaying extremely large tables neatly and speedily. I downloaded the package's necessary js and css files, and referenced them in the html getting loaded when i visit my site's url: mysite.com/popularify

```
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- uncommenting this line loading status files causes errors 
    <script src="{% static 'js/clusterize.min.js' %}"></script>
    -->

    <!-- I have a static/js/ folder -->

</head>

<body>
    <div>
        arthur russell = spotify:artist:3iJJD5v7oIFUevW4N5w5cj <br>

    <!--HTML-->
    <div class="clusterize">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Headers</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <div id="scrollArea" class="clusterize-scroll">
            <table>
                <tbody id="contentArea" class="clusterize-content">
                    <tr class="clusterize-no-data">
                        <td>Loading data…</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>

        // clusterize JavaScript
        var data = ['<tr>x</tr>', '<tr>z</tr>', '<tr>zxc</tr>'];
        var clusterize = new Clusterize({
            rows: data,
            scrollId: 'scrollArea',
            contentId: 'contentArea'
        });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
{% endblock content %}
```

And ensured that I have the two files in that location, when I try to access my site i am getting a 404 error only when I uncomment the line in my html file referencing the django static file.

My settings.py Django file has :

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    ]
```

How can I make my html page load these static files ?

Comment: What is there in background.js on line 50?

Comment: @harshitverma var lastChar = galleryArray[galleryPosition].substr(-1); its loading a javascript file which looks like one of the chrome extensions i am currently running,

Answer (score 0):

Looks like chrome version may not be compatible or it has something to do with the chrome extensions.

What you can do is to block **background.js** using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getScript("urlofscript");
});
```

To get the URL, hover on the background.js written on the inspection menu.

Hope this helps!

Comment: including that code in my <script> tag html leads to this error in console:     jquery.min.js:4 GET http://127.0.0.1:8054/urlofscript?_=1573024104900 404 (Not Found)  . I am loading jquery into my site with this line in the html file head: 
    <script> src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: i got the background.js error to go away. it was a seperate issue, I am still getting the same file not found errs

Comment: it's because the way you using the path to static file is not how django work, also don't disable things in browser randomly, those has nothing to do with your errors

Comment: I guess @Linh is correct, there is problem with your static files thats why it cannot find the right path

Answer (score 0):

You path to other static files also doesn't seem to be correct 
Django template support [staticfile tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/), so in your template at the top add `load staticfile` and include the static tag and the path is inside your static folder like so :

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">

<script src="{% static 'js/custom.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: Tried this, updated my question, am having trouble loading these static files

Comment: can you provide your project's hierarchy ?

Comment: Sure https://github.com/MartinBarker/publicWebsite/tree/master the page in question for this question is /popularify . You can see the url get redirected to martinbarker/urls.py -> /views.ya -> render the popularify.html page

Comment: your hierarchy seem to be correct, had you tried restart your django server yet ? also it's `{% load staticfiles %}` at the top and not `{% load static %}`

Comment: i restarted it, adding {% load staticfiles %} to popularify.html gets loaded, but then adding my js file with  <script src="{% static 'js/clusterize.min.js' %}"></script>
     produces a 404 error when i load the page

Comment: When I try to load my page /popularify , I get a 500 error for that route: "GET /popularify HTTP/1.1" 500 6326